# Couchbase - Creating a View and accessing its data immediatelly

Tags: java, view, couchbase

Say I a need an (automated) upgrade script which resets all users' balance if it's < 0

I would want to run a java code which:

1. Creates a view with an appropriate map function (i.e. only 'user' docs with balance < 0)
2. Scan the view and update users

I know how to create a view using 'CouchbaseClient.createDesignDoc' and how to query it using the View/Query Java API

What I am missing is two issues:

1. How can I publish that View to Production? currently the view is created in Development mode and thus scans only a subgroup of the 'user' documents
2. How can I make sure that once I created the View, it will be indexed on all data, **including data currently on Couchbase's Write queue**?

Thanks

Eyal

Answer (score 3):

I'll gladly answer my own question, and hope it helps the others

1.
To create a View in "Production Mode" you create it with any name but a name starting with "dev_" (!) --- I did not find any proper documentation to this little gimmick

So this will be your code:

```
// Production Mode Design Doc - no dev_ prefix in name!
DesignDocument designDoc = new DesignDocument("Users"); // not "dev_Users" !
ViewDesign viewDesign = new ViewDesign("NegativeBalance", mapFunction);
designDoc.getViews().add(viewDesign);
cbClient.createDesignDoc(designDoc);
```

2. 
**For couchbase 3.0 and newer**

To make sure you query the view and have all the results waiting, the view's stale property to FALSE

```
View view = client.getView("Users", "NegativeBalance"); // production Design Doc
Query query = new Query();
query.setStale(Stale.FALSE); // Read all data
```

This works great (and yes, stale=FALSE is a performance hit)

**For Couchbase 2.x and older**

Your update need to use stale=FALSE and PersistTo flag

```
client.ExecuteStore(StoreMode.Set, key, val, 
    Couchbase.Operations.PersistTo.One, 
    Couchbase.Operations.ReplicateTo.Zero);
```

[Details on couchbase blog](http://blog.couchbase.com/read-your-own-write-faster-in-3.0-incremental-map-reduce-views-with-couchbase-server)

Hope it helps

Eyal

Comment: Stale==False will only index data that is on disk, any writes/mutations that haven't yet been persisted won't be picked up in the view.

Comment: Very important comment, @scalabilitysolved, thanks -- I will update my answer --- Can we make CB write all changes to disk before creating the view?  ------ 


This is crucial as I want to be sure scanning an index is done on **ALL** items (either changed or created in previous operations)

Comment: Well you can use the PersistTo flag that observes the change until it is persisted to disk, however that comes at a performance cost.  Couchbase views are eventually consistent, and if your system is high throughput then observing and using Stale false will impact it a lot, plus the view still would be inconsistent due to the volume of data.

If user balances can't be less than 0 then that is something I'd have a business role in the code logic so that you don't end up in this situation.

Comment: I am experiencing an even greater issue: I call cbClient.createDesignDoc() to create my view and immediately afterwards query that view (with stale=false of course) - I get an exception saying "view_undefined" - probably the view wasn't created yet... Do you know how can I make sure it is before I continue querying it?

Comment: Even after changing the call to client.asyncCreateDesignDoc, verifying that the Future.get() returns true, the exception is still thrown - am I missing something?

Comment: I think this diverges from the original question, make a new one so that people can search for that specific issue and see the answers, too hard to provide info in the comments section.

Comment: Correct indeed, here's [the new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306216/couchbase-getting-view-undefined-after-accessing-a-newly-created-production)