# Couchbase - getting "view_undefined" after accessing a newly created Production View

Tags: java, view, couchbase

I'm creating a Production View in Couchbase using

```
HttpFuture<Boolean> asyncResult = client.asyncCreateDesignDoc(designDocProd);
Boolean success = asyncResult.get();
```

(Omitting the "dev_" prefix from the Design Doc's name creates it as Production View instead of Dev View)

After checking that success indeed equals true, I try to access the view using **couchbaseClient.query(view, query)** , but then I get the following Error:

```
SERVER: unknown_error Reason: view_undefined
```

(Below is the Full Stack Trace if neeeded)

If I add a sleep of 5 seconds, everything works well...

Anyone encountered this issue? am I missing something?

Thanks

Eyal

Full Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to access the view
    at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.query(CouchbaseClient.java:871)
    .
    .
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: OperationException: SERVER: unknown_error Reason: view_undefined
    at com.couchbase.client.internal.HttpFuture.waitForAndCheckOperation(HttpFuture.java:90)
    at com.couchbase.client.internal.HttpFuture.get(HttpFuture.java:74)
    at com.couchbase.client.internal.HttpFuture.get(HttpFuture.java:64)
    at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.query(CouchbaseClient.java:864)
... 54 more
Caused by: OperationException: SERVER: unknown_error Reason: view_undefined
    at com.couchbase.client.protocol.views.NoDocsOperationImpl.parseError(NoDocsOperationImpl.java:106)
    at com.couchbase.client.protocol.views.ViewOperationImpl.handleResponse(ViewOperationImpl.java:68)
    at com.couchbase.client.ViewNode$MyHttpRequestExecutionHandler.handleResponse(ViewNode.java:204)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.AsyncNHttpClientHandler.processResponse(AsyncNHttpClientHandler.java:417)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.AsyncNHttpClientHandler.inputReady(AsyncNHttpClientHandler.java:242)
    at com.couchbase.client.http.AsyncConnectionManager$ManagedClientHandler.inputReady(AsyncConnectionManager.java:249)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:172)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultClientIOEventDispatch.inputReady(DefaultClientIOEventDispatch.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:335)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:275)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:542)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: You should set system property "viewmode" to production or development before the connection to Couchbase.

e.g. System.setProperty('viewmode', 'development');  read more: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/couchbase-101-create-views-mapreduce-from-your-java-application.html

Comment: By default the viewmode is production, and this is the one I use... But how does it relate to the problem I presented? (i.e. that the view isn't found by CB even though I just created it)

Comment: Just try explicitly setting production view mode...may be it will make a difference...also try setting query.setStale(Stale.FALSE); for the first time you call that view...perhaps it will block until the view fully built.

Comment: I am setting stale=false in my Query. Why do you think it's an issue with 'production mode' ? specifically when the problem is 'solve' if I set a five second delay between the View creation and its query...

Comment: Well it was my guesses for you to try. Looks like CB takes some time (~5sec) to build index definitions. Are you planning to create indexes n-demand? If not then slight delay after index creation is not an issue in my opinion...since subsequent query calls have no such issues